# Java Regex to Match XML tags

Tags: java, regex

I am trying a figure out a regex pattern to match XML tags.

I have two kinds of XML tags. 
First kind

```
<myTag value="One" value="Two">SomeContentHere</myTag>
```

This tag I could match with the following regex pattern.

```
<myTag[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/myTag>
```

Second kind is, I have the same tag that appear as `<myTag value="One" value="Two"/>`. I struggle on finding a regex to match these kinds of XML tags. I need to match the entire XML like in the above matching in the first kind. My objective is to find a regex pattern that can capture both the above scenarios.

I tried something like `<myTag[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?[<\/myTag>]?` but, in this case, this pattern fails to capture my first XML tag type

Kindly help me.

Comment: Don't use regex for this. A common answer, I know. But if you're having trouble writing the regex yourself, you might not understand it, when you will return to this code. Rather use the indexOf method and substring, even if it might be a bit bloaty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• For your first type of tag use: `(<myTag)([\s\S]*?)(>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/myTag>)`

• For your second type of tag use: `(<myTag)([\s\S]*?)(\/>)`

• For both type at the same time use: `(<myTag)([\s\S]*?)(\/>)|(<myTag)([\s\S]*?)(>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/myTag>)`

[FirstTypeExample](https://regex101.com/r/mQGU7b/1/)

[SecondTypeExample](https://regex101.com/r/53tSoB/1/)

[BothTypeAtTheSameTimeExample](https://regex101.com/r/HVwcbv/1)

Comment: This does not work, My second XML type does not have </myTag> tag at the end.

Comment: Why do you escape the slashes? Why all these useless capture groups? What about nested tags?

Comment: Because I'm testing in javascript, and It expects `/` as `\/`. Those groups are given to visualize. And Nested Tags might not show up my REGEX.

Comment: For my usecase, this seem to be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of answers here in this community on why its bad to use regex for this. Having said that here is the approach for this problem. Convert your string to a Document if it is possible. It is possible if String is a valid xml. Then look for the desired tag in the Document. 
Code is :

```
private boolean containsTag(String xml, String tagName)
    {
        Document doc = getDocument(xml);
        if ( doc != null )
        {
           NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
           return list != null && list.getLength() > 0;
        }
        return false;
    }


    private static Document getDocument(String xml) 
    {

         try
         {
             DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
             Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
             return doc;
         } 
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
   }
```

Comment: This is a nice answer. Yet seems like, in this approach there is no way to replace a specific tag. Like, if `<myTag>SomeContent</myTag>` is present, then this should replace by `<myTag>ContentHidden</myTag>`. However, thanks for the answer. this is a nice idea.